# Cannot login with root after change limits.conf

Tags: linux, ulimit

I have changed my /etc/security/limits.conf and now cannot log in with root.

I do NOT have physical access to server console.

I DO know the root password.

I have tried:

```
ssh root@localhost 'echo "fs.file-max = 5000000" > /etc/sysctl.conf; echo "fs.nr_open = 5000000" >> /etc/sysctl.conf'
ssh root@localhost 'echo "root      hard    nofile      5000000" > /etc/security/limits.conf; echo "root      soft    nofile      5000000" >> /etc/security/limits.conf
```

but do not work, the command is not executed.

What can I do?

Thanks

Comment: If you have a regular (non-root) user account, have you tried su or sudo?

Comment: yes, do not work either

Comment: Same problem. When using `sudo`, there will be an error: `sudo: pam_open_session: Permission denied`